# Does Google ever remove a place from it's API or re-use the placeId?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

In Google Places, each place has a specific placeId.  We store this placeId and use it to retrieve information about the place as needed. For this approach to work, we need to confirm:

1. Is each placeId unique?
2. Does Google ever re-use a placeId?
3. Does Google ever delete a place from it's places database?
4. If they don't delete a place, do they just mark it as "permanently_closed"?

Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, each place has a unique ID.
2. No google do not re-use IDs. For each place in this world google have unique id for it.
3. Depends. Here, what google says,

> A place can only be deleted if: 1. It was added by the same application
>   as is requesting its deletion. 2. It has not successfully passed through
>   the Google Maps moderation process, and is therefore visible only to
>   the application that added it.

4. "INVALID_REQUEST" is what you get if you search for a place that has been deleted

Also for more info, here is a small notice from Google:

> Note: The id and reference fields are deprecated as of June 24, 2014. They are replaced by the new place ID, a unique identifier that can be used to compare places and to retrieve information about a place. The Places API currently returns a place_id in all responses, and accepts a placeid in the Place Details and Place Delete requests. Soon after June 24, 2015, the API will stop returning the id and reference fields in responses. Some time later, the API will no longer accept the reference in requests. We recommend that you update your code to use the new place ID instead of id and reference as soon as possible.

I hope I answered your questions, for more help, kindly comment, I'll reply. 
Reference:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will award the bounty even if points 3 and 4 are not really answered. The doc says that YOU can delete a place you created if it did not pass moderation, but that is not really the question. Under what conditions would Google remove a place from its database?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for bounty. As such google does not remove places from its database unless request comes from user side.

Comment: I'd disagree with the phrasing of point 2. PlaceIDs are stable, in that a placeid will always refer to one particular place, however we may have a collection of placeids that refer to a single place. Getting place details for a placeid will give you the latest one. Please see: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/place-id

Comment: Regarding whether the Google Places ever get deleted – yes. I am managing a database of all cinema venues where we track the associated Google Place IDs. Google Places associated with cinemas absolutely do get deleted, sometimes months after first being observed. However, the number is not that big: only 3 out of every 1000 were observed to be deleted in our case over the last year.