# If a placeId for a particular place gets removed, does Google ever allow that placeId to be re-used for different place?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

If a placeId for a particular place gets removed, does Google ever allow that placeId to be re-used for different place? Does that placeId ever go into the list of available placeIds that Google can use to assign to other places in the future or it's just used once and that's it?

I've read this: [Does Google ever remove a place from it's API or re-use the placeId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871128/does-google-ever-remove-a-place-from-its-api-or-re-use-the-placeid) and all it's told me is that if a place is using a particular placeId, no other place could use that same placeId. My question relates to if that placeId gets deleted, does Google allow that placeId to be used for other locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once a Place ID is deleted, it cannot be reused.